# Value of hidden field in jquery dialog is not passed to the asp.net mvc controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This is my CreateUnit.cshtml where I set the templateId into the hidden input field with the id 'TemplateId'. When I confirm the dialog the asp.net mvc controller 'UnitController' and its action method 'Create' is executed which should pass the UnitViewModel. Inside the UnitViewModel the model binder has set the name property to the value I entered. But the templateId from the hidden field is missing.

Why this?

```
@model ITMS.Web.Models.UnitViewModel

@*Remote Validation*@
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var templateId = $('#MyDialog').data('templateIdKey');
        $('#TemplateId').text(templateId);       
    }); 

</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Unit"))
{ 
     @Html.ValidationSummary(false)
    <p class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)</p>
    <p class="editor-field">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)</p>
    <p class="editor-field">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)</p> 

    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.TemplateId)      
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(UnitViewModel unitViewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid && !_dataProvider.UnitExists(unitViewModel.Name, unitViewModel.TemplateId))
    {
        Unit unit = Mapper.Map<UnitViewModel, Unit>(unitViewModel);
        _dataProvider.AddUnit(unit);
        return new JsonNetResult(new { success = true });
    }
    ModelState.AddModelError("Name", "This name already exists.");
    return PartialView(unitViewModel);
}

 public class UnitViewModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name must not be empty.")]
        [StringLength(30, ErrorMessage = "Enter max. 30 chars for a name.")]
        [Remote("UnitExists", "Unit", ErrorMessage = "This name already exists.",AdditionalFields="TemplateId")]
        [JsonProperty("title")]
        public string Name { get; set; }  

        public Nullable<int> ParentId { get; set; }

        [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
        public int TemplateId { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Instead of:**

$('#TemplateId').text(templateId);

**I wrote this and now the TemplateId is sent with the form** :)

$("[name='TemplateId']").val(templateId);

stupid from me the input field has no text ...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.TemplateId)` in your view, use `@Html.EditorFor(x => x.TemplateId)` instead. The HTML will be rendered as a hidden input field.

Comment: Your adivse did not help and i ask myself why should have helped me? A hidden field is a hidden field.

Comment: ok seems the problem is this:  var templateId = $('#MyDialog').data('templateIdKey'); the data property always returns an empty templateId thus the model binder passes null...

Comment: ok I fixed the .data() method problem of jquery dialog. But still the TemplateId is not send with the form :/